# How to deal with currency symbols when combined with other units

Tags: measuring-units, money, convention, formatting, international

It seems that pretty much all documentation I've read is clear on where to place the currency symbol when dealing with currency amounts in English (let us assume English from UK for this example):

- £100
- €100
- GBP 100
- EUR 100

So, basically, the currency symbol comes before the number and the space is only used when using ISO codes.

However, for all other units I assume the convention is the international standard (units on the right and separated with a space):

- 100 m (meters)
- 50 s (seconds)

So, what is the rule to follow when units are currency per meter (imagine the price of a metal rod) or currency per time (price of an international phone call)?

- 100 €/m ?
- 100 EUR/m ?
- EUR 100 /m ?? (seems broken)
- £100 /m ?? (seems broken)

If 100 €/m (SI) is the way to go, would using SI for currency be still considered as incorrect or could it be accepted even though considered uncommon? (i.e.: 100 €)

Comment: Try this style guide, it's great: https://www.stylemanual.gov.au/grammar-punctuation-and-conventions/numbers-and-measurements/currency

Comment: Different countries will have different conventions, and even within a single country, you may have differing conventions for different languages (for example, in English-speaking Canada, one writes $100, but in Québec it's 100$. I'd recommend consulting a style guide for the country and language you're writing in.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin As stated in the question we can restrict answers to UK for simplicity.

Comment: In which case my advice still stands; I note that @Lambie provided a link to a style guide for _Australia_, not the UK. I'm in the US, so specifics for the way I generally see it would not be appropriate. In the UK, I could _conceive_, without actually knowing for sure, of many different answers that might be valid (English, Scots Gaelic, Welsh, Manx, and the local dialects for Guernsey and Jersey), which is why I suggest always consulting local resources for the target country _and language_.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thanks! As also stated in the question, I would restrict it to English from UK. I'll leave here the original link that Lambie posted for reference (a link to the London Stock Exchange): https://www.londonstockexchange.com/discover/news-and-insights/london-stock-exchange-welcomes-jp-morgan-asset-management-celebrate-launch-jpm-global-equity-premium-income-ucits-etf

Comment: As a bit of anecdotal evidence, long distance calls in the US always seem to be priced as "75 cents per minute" or "$1.25 per minute" or whatever the price is - the "per minute" appears to always be written out in words, rather than in the slash notation. This might be a reasonable usage for any of your example cases - "£3 per metre" for the metal rod, for example.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Actually, this is usually a style guide thing. The Australian one explains totally well even for US uses: $40.00, for example.  And: GBP50.00 OR £50 In texts, there are generally no spaces between the currency name and the amount.

Comment: SI compound units often use negative indices rather than 'per' or the solidus. Thus 10ms⁻²;  kgm⁻³.  No gap before the derived unit (or any other). With currency, there is no corresponding scientific convention. I'd advise a 'per' as in say £4000 per kg (or £4000 / kg) and I prefer a gap where there is no orthography czar.

Comment: @Lambie - Except for those currencies where there is/was a space (e.g., the pre-Euro Greek and German currencies always wrote the delta-rho or DM after the value, separated by a space (100 DM, 1'000 Dr)). That's why I recommended the localized style guide in the first place, and noted that in the case of price per unit, I generally didn't see the slash notation used, but with the "per" spelled out in full.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - with currency, my inclinations are a close match to yours, when there is no formal definition somewhere, but with currency, I would never use the solidus - always "per" spelled out.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Nope: There is continuity of style with what I wrote: DM 40 million, except with a space: The principal amount of the issue is DM 200 million. https://www.worldbank.org/en/news/press-release/1971/05/13/world-bank-signs-agreement-on-dm-200-million-bond-issue Who is talking about per kilo? Is that part of the question?? The slash is not used with currencies.

Comment: 'Jeff Zeitlin 'Diesel prices have dropped from 149.7 p/litre to 147.8 p/litre' [[The AA; 2024](https://www.theaa.com/driving-advice/driving-costs/fuel-prices)] // 'The cheapest I paid personally was 458.7p/gallon' [[Speedlimit.org.UK](http://www.speedlimit.org.uk/petrolprices.html)] // 'COPPER £3.50 – £6.50 / kg' [[Transmetal.co.UK](https://transmetal.co.uk/scrap-prices/)] ...

Comment: @Lambie, The question **is** about **combining** currency symbols with per kilogramme/metre/mile/minute/etc. The OP is well aware how to use the currency symbols by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

As the question correctly points out, every possible way of using slashes in the contexts of this kind is bound to be awkward in some way. The only elegant way of dealing with the matter (where there is no style manual that explicitly covers it) is the one suggested in a comment by Mr Zeitlin, which is to not use slashes at all, but the word *per*, followed by the unit written out in full: e.g. '$1.25 per minute', '£3 per metre'.

Comment: Journals and institutions may have style guides, but Zeitlin suggests that countries have style guides, of which I have never seen.  (Please show me examples if they do.)  In technical fields it is common to use the slash and there is no compelling reason to ditch it in favor of "per".  Even with currency symbols, units such as, $/lb, €/m, or CNY/s are commonplace.